# Has Germany’s migrant policy improved the economy?

Tags: germany

What causal relationship is there, if any, between the country’s 2015-17 migrant policy and its economic growth?

Comment: You might want to check the [OECD paper](https://www.oecd.org/migration/OECD%20Migration%20Policy%20Debates%20Numero%202.pdf) on migration effects in the economy, or  the [Migration policy debates](http://www.oecd.org/migration/migration-policy-debates.htm) page.
Maybe you could improve your question with the time period you refer to - I'm assuming the latest 2015-17 migrant policy with the Syrian refugee crisis, right?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Correct, I'm referring to the 2015-17 migrant policy and will edit that in.

Comment: The positive economic effects of recent migration to Germany are likely to be long-term, possibly by addressing demographic issues as native Germans age

Comment: Simple answer, No. I second @Henry, it may take a few decades for the current wave of migration to have any "causal" effect on growth. Take the US, migration from Eastern Europe to the US back in early 20th century has had positive effects in the long run. But it took a decade for the first generation migrants to integrate into the society and then for the second generation to have a decent education, it took much longer. This second generation migrants have made significant contributions to growth. Today's Nobel prize winning economists and scientists are mostly second generation migrants.